# Socket programming in c: #define DATA "Long piece of string" vs #define DATA argv[2]

Tags: string, sockets, parsing, server, client

I simply have run out of ideas. 
After following [this codethrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFLQkmnmD0o) which deals with socket programming in c I wanted to add some funtionality.

In the video the message to be send from the client to the server is hardcoded into the client.c file, like so

`#define DATA "String to send to server"`

I wanted to be able to parse a string from the command line instead, like so

```
./client localhost "String to send to server"
```

This was done by defining

```
#define DATA argv[2]
```

The problem is that if I hardcode the string into the c file the full message is passed through but if I do the argv[2] only the first 4 characters show up on the output from the server, kind of like this:

```
client(12345) -> server(12345)

client 12345 -> server(1234)
```

What am I doing wrong here ? It must be on the client side since it works as long as the message to send is hardcoded into the client.c file.

Full code can be found at my [Github](https://github.com/MarcusTherkildsen/socket_c).